# How many hands of five cards contain cards from exactly three suits?

Tags: combinations, card-games

I have been trying to solve this but I stink at this kind of math. What I have is

(4 choose 3)(13 choose 2)(13 choose 2)(13 choose 1)=316,368.

Is this answer right or wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you are assuming the suit distribution is $2,2,1$.  But it could also be $3,1,1$.

Comment: So would it be (4 choose 3)(13 choose 2)(13 choose 2)(13 choose 1)+(4 choose 3)(13 choose 3)(13 choose 1)(13 choose1)?

Comment: No, you are still off by a factor of 3 because in each case one suit has a different count than the other two.

Comment: You are not just choosing three suits; you are choosing two to have the same number of kinds, and one to have a different number. (Two doubles and a single, *or* two singles and a triple.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, but you also need to account for the choice of which suit gets only 1 card (or which suit gets 3 cards in the case of 3,1,1).

Here's an alternative approach.  There are $\binom{52}{5}$ five-card hands in total.

- $\binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{5}$ contain exactly 1 suit.
- $\binom{4}{2}\sum_{k=1}^4 \binom{13}{k}\binom{13}{5-k}$ contain exactly 2 suits.
- $\binom{4}{4}\binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{1}^3$ contain exactly 4 suits.

Now subtract these three counts from $\binom{52}{5}$, yielding $1529112$.

Comment: In addition to as David noted in the comments above accounting for distributions other than 2-2-1.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A five-card hand will contain exactly three suits when it contains either of:

- (Two doubles and a single) *Two from the thirteen* kinds in **each** of *two from the four* suits, and *one from the thirteen* kinds in *one from the two* remaining suits, *or*
- (Two singles and a tripple) *One from the thirteen* kinds in **each** of *two from the four* suits, and *three from thirteen* kinds in *one from the two* remaining suits.

Comment: So would it be (4 choose 3)(13 choose 2)(13 choose 2)(13 choose 1)+(4 choose 3)(13 choose 3)(13 choose 1)(13 choose1)?

Comment: No.  You have to choose which *two* of the suits have doubles and which *one* has a single or which *two* have singles and which *one* has a triple.